# BigQuery - Get distinct values up to a given point in time

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that contains the actions of a user (e.g. view page, click button, etc). Each row contains a user_id a date (created_on) and the name of the action. I would like to create a query that for each date it would create a nested field of the distinct actions taken up to and including that date. For example, I have a table called `user_actions`:

```
-------------------------------------
| user_id |    date    |   action   |
-------------------------------------
|    1    | 2018-04-01 |    click   |
|    2    | 2018-04-01 |     view   |
|    1    | 2018-04-02 |     view   |
|    2    | 2018-04-02 |     view   |
|    2    | 2018-04-03 |      buy   |
-------------------------------------

would result in

-------------------------------------
| user_id |    date    |   actions  |
-------------------------------------
|    1    | 2018-04-01 |     click  |
|    2    | 2018-04-01 |     view   |
|    1    | 2018-04-02 |     click  |
|    2    | 2018-04-02 |     view   |
|         |            |     view   |
|    2    | 2018-04-03 |     view   |
|    2    |            |      buy   |
-------------------------------------
```

In the second table, actions is a nested repeated field. I know that for a single point in time I can use something similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    date,
    ARRAY(action)
FROM
    user_actions
GROUP BY
    1,2
```

However I am unsure how to extend this out to provide the same calculation for every date in the original table and only look at the time before the `date` field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> create a nested field of the distinct actions taken up to and including that date

Below is for BigQuery Standrad SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, date, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT action FROM UNNEST(actions) action
  ) actions
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, date, ARRAY_AGG(action) OVER(win) actions
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from  your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 user_id, '2018-04-01' date, 'click' action UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-04-01', 'view' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-04-02', 'view' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-04-02', 'view' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-04-03', 'buy' 
)
SELECT user_id, date, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT action FROM UNNEST(actions) action
  ) actions
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, date, ARRAY_AGG(action) OVER(win) actions
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
)
-- ORDER BY date, user_id
```

with result

[image]

> Update

Below version supports more generic case with multiple actions for same user within same day (I realized it was not a case with my initial answer)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, date, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT action FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(actions)) action
  ) actions
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, date , STRING_AGG(actions) OVER(win) actions
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, date, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT action) actions
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY user_id, date
  )
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
)
```

You can test it with below sample data (note extyra row with activity = 'play' )

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 user_id, DATE '2018-04-01' date, 'click' action UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-04-01', 'view' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-04-02', 'view' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-04-02', 'play' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-04-02', 'view' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-04-03', 'buy' 
)
SELECT user_id, date, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT action FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(actions)) action
  ) actions
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, date , STRING_AGG(actions) OVER(win) actions
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, date, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT action) actions
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY user_id, date
  )
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )
)
-- ORDER BY date, user_id
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the great answer! I didn't realize the window function part.